# Can I get family member's Health Data with HealthKit? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-watch, healthkit

In iPhone Health App, My family has shared information to me. Can I get these information in my app?

I try to get information in "Healthkit", but I can always obtain personal data only. Is there any way to get family health data?

Comment: No.  It is a privacy issue.  They may have shared data with you, but they have not consented to sharing the data with some other app.  As an individual you can decide if you want to share your health data with an app.  You cannot consent for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer:

To  access health data, an app needs to request access from the user.  The user can decide if they want to share the data with the app and what data they want to share.  Before sharing they may consider the data that is being requested, the privacy policy of the app and so on.

If an app was able to access family health data that had been shared with you then the family member is being denied the opportunity to decide what data to share or whether to share any data with the app.  You cannot consent to the sharing on their behalf.